# Making changes to git pull request locally, after numerous merge conflicts resolved in Github GUI

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I've got a pull request I've been trying to get merged.  The first time I submitted it, there ended up being a merge conflict first, and in the process of trying to fix it locally, I ended up "dirtying" up the PR with dozens of other people's commits ending up in there, rather than the 1 or 2 cleanly rebased & squashed commits that were originally there.

I closed the PR, I dug through the diffs and recreated the branch & PR based off the newer upstream master, and it's been sitting for about a week.  In the meanwhile, there were two merge conflicts I resolved ON GITHUB, such that in the commit history, its clean and shows just my initial squashed commit, and the two force-pushed resolved conflicts.

The maintainer has asked me to make a couple easy changes before merging, but I want to avoid the mess I made the first time. At his suggestion, I deleted my LOCAL branch, and pulled it from my fork again, but it's showing up one commit short for some reason, without the newest merge conflict resolved.

I'm so confused truth be told, and I just can't figure out how I'm supposed to do this.  Can anyone help me out?

Here is the PR:
https://github.com/WikiEducationFoundation/WikiEduDashboard/pull/3481/

Here is my local fork, selected to the appropriate feature branch where I did all the work:
https://github.com/chrisnorwood/WikiEduDashboard/tree/feature/convert-alerts-list-to-react-2

I deleted my local branch and repulled it with the following command:
`git co -b feature/convert-alerts-list-to-react-2 origin/feature/convert-alerts-list-to-react-2`

When I run `git log` on the newly pulled branch, it shows `51cc7be50...` as the latest commit (Nov. 15th), but not `a029135e42...` (Nov 21) as shown on Github.com ....  is that weird?

**How can I get the correct version of the branch, with all relevant commits locally, so when I push to my fork again, the PR is updated without showing like 50+ other people's commits in there????**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The maintainer has asked me to make a couple easy changes before merging

Then no need to delete everything: make your changes on your local PR branch and push: it will update the PR automatically, and notify the maintainer.

But if you already deleted/recloned, to be sure to get the original repo ID:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/WikiEducationFoundation/WikiEduDashboard
git fetch upstream 
git fetch upstream pull/3481/head:feature/convert-alerts-list-to-react-2 
git switch feature/convert-alerts-list-to-react-2
... # work, commits
git push -u origin feature/convert-alerts-list-to-react-2
```

Comment: So the issue I had last time, was when I merged the new commits to my local branch and pushed back to MY fork, was that the PR now showed like 25 commits (all other stuff fixed in other PRs for instance).

To be clear, I didn't delete everything by any means.  I deleted only my local feature branch, and attempted to pull MY remote feature branch (from MY fork), and its not grabbing all the commits.  The upstream is still set appropriately, the origin (my fork) is still set correctly.

The line about fetching the feature branch from the upstream pull request might be relevant, let me try...

Comment: @C.Norwood Yes, fetching directly the right PR branch (and creating a local branch at the same time) seems safer: no merge.

Comment: that worked exactly as needed!  I'm not sure what happened last time to add all the extra commits, but I must have done things in way that made past commits have new hashes or something.

Anyway, all is well. I got my local branch back to where it needed, changes made, & pushed! Thanks for your help.